# Атрибут autoplay не работает

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте не работает атрибут autoplay. В интернете нашел решение запихнуть его в видео, но 1 оно даже так не работает и 2 люди говорят что это неправильно. Подскажите пожалуйста что делать?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <audio autoplay>
    <source src="audio/intro.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Путь звука]

Comment: Не хотеть этого. Люди в среднем очень не любят когда вдруг откуда-то начинает что-то звучать.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

Answer (score 1):

Несмотря на то, что у `<audio>` и `<video>` есть атрибут `autoplay`, который запустит воспроизведение автоматически, во многих браузерах это работать не будет, т.к. многих людей это бесит.

Представьте ситуацию, вы сидите ночью на колонках, заходите на какой-то сайт и что-то где-то начинает орать (если б многие писали изначально `.volume = .25`, может быть удалось бы избежать отключение браузерами автовоспроизведения), а вы в это время пытаетесь найти как это выключить или же вовсе закрываете вкладку\браузер.

Мало приятного, согласитесь, по этому некоторые браузеры ограничили этот атрибут.

Например `<video autoplay>` будет работать только при наличии атрибута `muted`.

А как быть с `<audio>`?

Одно из решений, которое в целом не запрещено, это воспроизвести аудио, как только пользователь кликнул где-то на странице.

```js
const audio = document.querySelector('#audio');

audio.pause();
audio.volume = .25;

document.addEventListener('click', AudioPlay);

function AudioPlay() {
  audio.play();
  document.removeEventListener('click', AudioPlay);
}
```

```html
<p>Кликните по странице, чтобы воспроизвести</p>
<audio id="audio" src="//minov.pw/_remove/ruso/audio.mp3" preload="auto" autoplay controls></audio>
```

Comment: Я понял спасибо большое